# USB flash drive is showing no media status, how to repair the USB drive irrespective of the data loss?

Tags: usb, partitioning, usb-flash-drive, recovery

So I tried converting a USB flash drive (16 gb) to live usb for a Linux distribution, Not going into details, it ended with me deleting those files and trying to format the USB drive and this happened to the USB drive.

[You can see the drive is grayed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdMec.png)

I tried formatting it, and it showed

"There is no disk in drive E:

Insert a disk, and then try again."

Then I tried using disk management, changing the letter and so on, and it showed this
[disk management screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIemm.png)

I also tried using deskpart, but it still didn't worked.
It showed:

```
Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
--------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
Disk 1    No Media           0 B      0 B
```

What should I do to make the usb drive workable again? I am fine if all the data is lost because it wasn't important, but I would like the USB drive to work again.

Comment: @Tetsujin, Thank you for the comment, I will try the methods in the answers

Comment: @Tetsujin I tried the methods in the answer, it didn't work. Rufus didn't even detect the usb flash drive. And I also installed HP recovery tool for USB, it detected the flash drive but couldn't format it as there is no media in it

Comment: The other question is more an explanation of how it's broken permanently than how to make it work again. Flash drives are very fragile & just die for no apparent reason. Usually the only thing to do unless data on it is valuable is bin it & buy another.